# sql how to set default values on null fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named "id". What I want to do is when user want to save an object, I must check this object's id and if it is null then I will save this object's id with its default value. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to figure out if an update is going to happen or an insert ?

Comment: Why not use `DEFAULT` modifier for type definition?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I really don't understand what Default value does. What I want to do is if field is empty then use default value while saving.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this example:

```
create table foo (id int auto_increment primary key, another_id int default 10);

insert into foo (another_id) values (1);
insert into foo (id) values (3);
insert into foo (another_id) values (2);
insert into foo (another_id) values (null);
```

Result of `select * from foo;` will be:

```
| ID | ANOTHER_ID |
-----|------------|
|  1 |          1 |
|  3 |         10 |
|  4 |          2 |
|  5 |     (null) |
```

When you don't specify a value the default value is saved (like you specified in create table statement). When you specify another (or same as default) value in insert statement, this value will be inserted.

You can play around with it a bit [here in this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5089b/1/0).

Comment: Now I got it thanks.What I want to do is "If id is null Then use default value". I did a little research and found out that I need to use plsql. Is there any other way?

Comment: Well, if you want to use the "built-in" default value, you just don't specify the column and it's value in the insert statement. What do you mean with "is there another way"? And why do you need plsql? Are the insert statements built dynamically?